# Tableview list is empty causes by findObjectInBackgroundWithBlock return nil

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, parse-platform, pfobject

These are my code in swift
This is the code of retrieving the current user's friend list object with parse

```
class UserViewController: UITableViewController {

var userArray: NSMutableArray = []

@IBOutlet weak var friendListTableView: UITableView!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

       retrieveMessages()

   }
func retrieveMessages() {
    var query = PFUser.query()
    if let username = PFUser.currentUser().username {
        query.whereKey("username", equalTo: username)
        query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
        (objects, error) -> Void in

        for object in objects! {
            let usernames:String? = (object as PFObject)["Friends"] as? String
            println(usernames) // It prints "nil"
            if usernames != nil {
                self.userArray.addObject(usernames!)
            }
        }
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                    self.friendListTableView.reloadData()
                }

    }

}
}
            override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

// MARK: - Table view data source

override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    // #warning Potentially incomplete method implementation.
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete method implementation.
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return userArray.count
}


override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    // Update - replace as with as!

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell

    cell.textLabel?.text = userArray[indexPath.row] as? String

    return cell
}
```

and this is the code of saving current user's friend when the current user add them via username with parse

```
class addUserViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var usernameTextField: UITextField!

@IBAction func addUser(sender: AnyObject) {
    var query = PFUser.query()
    query.whereKey("username", equalTo: usernameTextField.text)
    println("Pass")
    query.getFirstObjectInBackgroundWithBlock{ (object:PFObject!, error: NSError!) -> Void in

        if error == nil {
            let currentUser = PFUser.currentUser()
            let friendList = currentUser.relationForKey("Friends")

            var addFriend = object
            if addFriend != nil {
                friendList.addObject(addFriend)
                println("added")
            }
            PFUser.currentUser().saveInBackgroundWithBlock{
                (succeeded: Bool!, error: NSError!) in

                if error != nil {
                    println("Error")
                }
                else {
                    println("saved")
                }
            }
        }

    }
}
```

I want to retrieve current user's friend list to show it in tableview but the tableview won't update to show current user's friend list, It's empty and there's no user list in tableview at all. I've tried to fix it and check if method get any object.

The problem is when I use println(usernames) ,It prints "nil" which the method doesn't get any object at all. First I use username as NSArray then I changed it into NSMutableArray and it doesn't have append method like NSArray did so I did a research and add the "add object" line of code in it and change a few things. Right now I'm not sure at all what's wrong with my code and I've been stuck at this for a week now, If my code's wrong somehow can you please guide me where? or fix it would be great. Any help is appreciated

here's the screenshot of my User's class table in parse
https://www.dropbox.com/s/6xp48v3yn0l2hje/Screen%20Shot%202015-06-03%20at%202.10.13%20PM.png?dl=0

here's the screenshot of my current user's friend in parse which is saveก with PFRelation method as seen above 
https://www.dropbox.com/s/pd8mt8sf35u1m0v/Screen%20Shot%202015-06-03%20at%202.10.55%20PM.png?dl=0

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Where are you checking your array that shows it's empty? You should be calling reloadData on the table view in the completion block if the `findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock`

Comment: I check it below the line of code where usernames variable was declared